# Are there any public statistic available for the most common FTP servers

Tags: ftp

I'm looking for information on what the most common FTP server software is. This information is [readily available for web server software](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/category/web-server-survey/), but I can't find the equivalent for FTP server software. Is this information available anywhere?

The goal of this is for an FTP client being created. Clients have different options available and different responses to errors, so having a list of servers that could be tested against would be helpful. Straight implementation of the FTP spec seems to be only partway to what we need. Knowing common servers to test against would be helpful to make sure all cases are handled correctly.

Comment: I can't imagine that this would be very accurate since you can't always just access any ftp server. Also a lot of FTP servers in  a corporate environment are only available from a LAN or VPN network.

Comment: What is the purpose of gathering this information? If you added that to your question, it would most likely make it easier to get you the information you're after.

Comment: @LucasKauffman This is definitely something I'd considered. This confound I'm not worried about for my case though since most of my users will not be in this group of people. They will be uploading, most of the time, to web servers/hosts that have ftp enabled.